# не работает keylistener

Tags: java

Почему не реагирует на нажатие клавиш?

Я уже миллион статей перечитал, вроде всё нормально должно быть.
Да код не очень, но суть вопроса в `KeyListener`.

```
public Game() {
    setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    initgame();
    loadimage();
    addKeyListener(new FieldKeyListener());
    setFocusable(true);
    requestFocus();
}

public void initgame(){
    this.x=160;
    this.y=610;
    timer= new Timer(50, this);
    timer.start();
    createblock();
}

public void createblock(){
    blocks[currentblock]=new Random().nextInt(units);

    for(int i=0;i<blocks[currentblock];i++){
        groundplace[currentblock][i]=new Random().nextInt(units);
    }
    for (int i=1;i<units;i++){
       blockX[i]=i*16;
    }
}

public void loadimage(){
    ImageIcon imc = new ImageIcon("12.png");
    Mycar=imc.getImage();
    ImageIcon iec = new ImageIcon("12.png");
    Enemycar=iec.getImage();
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
     super.paintComponent(g);
     g.drawImage(Mycar,x,y,this);

     for(int j=0;j<=currentblock;j++){
         for(int i=0;i<blocks[j];i++){
             g.drawImage(Enemycar, blockX[groundplace[j][i]], blockY[j], this);
         }
     }

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  move();
  for(int i=0;i<=currentblock;i++){
      blockY[i]+=DOT_SIZE/8;
  }
  if(t_n==0){
      t_n=System.currentTimeMillis();
      t_f=t_n+t_d;
  }
  if(t_f<=System.currentTimeMillis()){
      currentblock++;
      createblock();
      t_n=0;
  }
  if(blockY[2]==600){
      currentblock=0;
  }
  repaint();
}

 public void move(){
    if(left){
        x -= DOT_SIZE;
    }
    if(right){
        x += DOT_SIZE;
    } 
    if(up){
        y -= DOT_SIZE;
    } 
    if(down){
        y += DOT_SIZE;
    }
 }



class FieldKeyListener implements KeyListener{       
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
       // super.keyPressed(e);
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A){
          left=true;
        }
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
           right=true;
        }

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP ){
            up=true;
        }
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
            down=true;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

Comment: Посмотрите вызывается ли вообще слушатель, если да, то какие кнопки приходят

Comment: Game наследует JFrame?

Comment: Game наследует JPanel, проверить создается ли объект класса FieldKeyListener?? если да то он создаётся, ну как проверить какие кнопки он ловит не знаю.

Comment: @Esseker System.out.println(); в помощь

Comment: Проблема явно в фокусе:\
вот таким незамысловатым образом я смотрю где фокус
System.out.println(java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getFocusOwner());
и в ответ мне только- null
как сделать фокус если setFocusable(true) не работает?

Comment: Всё разобрался... В JFrame.  когда добавляю панель:
add(new Game()).requestFocus();
помогло

Answer (score 1):

Обычно проблема заключается в том, что фокус находится на другом элементе, и он первым перехватывает событие. 
Есть вариант сделать остальные элементы

```
setFocusable(False);
```

Если они получают фокус.

Comment: У меня вроде и элементов других нету